# How to run a single-threaded application on multiple processor cores efficiently?

Tags: virtualization, central-processing-unit, threads, multi-threading

There is this old application that we are using (called Aldfaer) that only uses a single thread. One of its processes takes about 90 minutes to complete at this moment, and we would like to decrease the time it takes for this job to complete. For this, we would like to run this single thread over multiple CPU's.

Does anyone know of any method to accomplish this? This may even be with CPU virtualization or something like that.

Comment: There isn't one.

Comment: This is way too generic a description of the problem. To give you any kind of useful help, we'd need much more specific information.

Comment: And...did you really ask us how to speed up your genealogy program?

Comment: No, unfortunately the only option (as expected) was to upgrade the CPU, and we already have a 3.66GHz CPU in it, so upgrading will be expensive. (relative to the PC price). I was hoping it would be possible using Hyper-V or VMware and a single virtualized CPU with better specs.

Comment: I don't know why, yet another question is closed as "off-topic" by our great team of dictators (oops... mediators). My entire life, when I was in school I was told that there is no such thing as a "stupid question". And sometimes, even though there is NO specific or exact answer, the discussion can lead to great resolution or result. I can see a half dozen suggestions that could be given to that guy from I/O issues, memory, palatalization, faster CPU, smaller data-sets, etc, etc. Which would be of value to ALL. But no, once again these bright minds decide to close off all discussions.

Answer (score 2):

If the data, that the application processes can be divided into smaller packs, you can run multiple copies of the application, each processing part of the data and then try to put together the result (i.e. with a script).

Answer (score 2):

What you describe is not possible. Buy a computer with the fastest CPU you can find (number of cores/threads is unimportant).